# Problem on $n\times n$ chess board

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is:

> We call a positive integer $n\geq4$ "good" if we can somehow write $n^2$ real numbers (not necessarily distinct) on every square of a $n\times n$ chessboard such that sum of numbers on every $3\times 3$ grid is positive and sum of numbers on every $4\times 4$ grid is negative. Find all good numbers.

I claim that

> If $n\times n$ is good then $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ is also good. We just need to cut a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grid out of $n\times n$ chessboard.

and

> $n=5$ is a good number:
> $$|-1 |-1 |-1| -1| -1|$$
> $$|-1| -2| +2| -2| -1|$$
> $$|-1|+2|+4|+2|-1|$$
> $$|-1| -2| +2| -2| -1|$$
> $$|-1 |-1 |-1| -1| -1|$$

and

> $n=12$ is not a good number: We divide $12\times 12$ chessboard into $16$ $3\times 3$ grids to claim that sum of all numbers on the board is positive and divide it into $9$ $4\times 4$ grids to claim that sum of all numbers is negative (a contradiction).

Hence all $n\geq 12$ is not good. However I don't know if $n=6,7,8,9,10,11$ is good. I feel that $6$ is not a good number.

Comment: Interesting problem, you can generalize to $n\times n$ being positive and $m\times m$ being negative and you get the largest possible grid size $f(n,m)$ is a positive integer at most $\mbox{lcm}(n,m)$. Have you tried looking at $f(2,3)$? Also, you should be able to simply insert the problem into a linear programming solver, requiring every $3\times3$ is at least $1$ and every $4\times4$ is at most $-1$.

Comment: In general we have $f(n,n+1)\geq2n-1$ by placing $n^2-1$ in the middle, $0$ on the rest of the middle row and column, and $-1$ everywhere else. This generalizes $f(3,4)\geq5$ :)

Comment: By your hint, I can make sure that $6$ is a good number because we have $36$ variables together with $16+9=25$  equations ($16$ $3\times 3-$girds and $9$ $4\times 4-$grids). But I still don't know if $11$ is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a $6\times 6$ board. Sum of all $16$ $3\times 3-$grid = sum of all $9$ $4\times 4-$grid so $n=6$ is not a good number. We are done!

PS: Any unit square belongs to the same number of $3\times 3$'s and $4\times 4$'s.

Comment: What a surprisingly simple argument! Using the notation in my comment this shows $f(n,n+1)=2n-1$ for all $n$. It seems this coincidence can only occur in this special case $m=n+1$, which is perhaps even more surprising. In fact $f(3,5)\geq6$ holds by placing $1$ everywhere but $-7$ in places $(2,2),(5,2),(2,5),(5,5)$.